# Swift dispatch_async not updating UIView until iOS notification

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiview, swift2

I have a UIView that is updated from a server once a button is pushed.

The UIView update happens within a dispatch_async(). Through debugging I can see that the server response has been received and the new subview is created and applied to the UIView.

However the view remains unchanged *UNTIL* another iOS notification occurs (e.g. the device receives an email). As soon as the notification banner is displayed the UIView is refreshed and displays the image from the server.

What am I missing? How do I get the UIView to update as soon as the new subview is added?

Note: I have tried the following within and outside the dispatch_async() and tried calling them on the same queue after the initial change takes place without luck.

- self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
- self.view.bringSubviewToFront(view)
- self.view.layoutIfNeeded() (thanks for the suggestion @buxik)

**EDIT** added code (small version of larger class, only relevant section added):

```
   class networkedImage: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var viewArea: UIView = UIView()
    let originalWidth: CGFloat = 200
    let originalHeight: CGFloat = 100
    let imageURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "www.example.com/image.jpg")!

    func updateViewArea() {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.viewArea.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

      let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.originalWidth, self.originalHeight))
      let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.imageURL)
      if data != nil {
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        if image != nil {
          newImageView.image = image

          self.viewArea.addSubview(newImageView)
          self.viewArea.bringSubviewToFront(newImageView)
          self.viewArea.setNeedsDisplay()
        }

         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: {
         [unowned self] note in
         print("I thought this might work, it didn't.")
         })
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @buxik no luck, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you make the update on the main queue ?  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())

Comment: Adding the relevant code to the question will help people identify where the problem lies. Without seeing that, it could easily be caused by any number of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I added an Observer to viewDidLoad()

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("imageReadyNotification", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: {
        [unowned self] note in
        self.updateViewArea()
        })
```

Then at the bottom of updateViewArea() I post the notification

```
                if self.newImage == true {
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("imageReadyNotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            }
```

The if condition is to ensure the notification isn't fired continually. I have no idea why calling this function twice works, but it does.